# Caffeine concentration method!

Tags: organic-chemistry, concentration, extraction

I'm trying to measure the concentration of caffeine after the extraction process. If I dissolve the same amount of extracted caffeine into same amount of distilled water, will I be able to calculate the concentration of caffeine?

Comment: Which analysis method will you use?

Comment: I'm using the DCM (organic solvent) method

Comment: 1) Measure mass of extract 2) Evaporate water or other solvents 3)Measure mass of precipitate 4) Concentration by mass= $\frac{precipitate}{mass of extract}$

Comment: what do you mean by the mass of extract? Is it the mass of water and coffee at the beginning of the experiment? or is it the mass of extract after filtering through separatory funnel?

Comment: @yjasz98 It depends. If you want to measure the the concentration of caffeine of "the mass of water and coffee at the beginning" then you can use "the mass of water and coffee at the beginning" as the denominator. If you want to get the concentration of caffeine "after filtering through separatory funnel" then use the mass of "after filtering through separatory funnel"

Comment: However, if I were you, I would use the mass after filtering through separatory funnel. There are lots of other things in coffee other than caffeine. So using the mass after the separatory funnel will probably be more accurate.

Comment: What is filtering through a separatory funnel? A separatory funnel isn't for filtering, it's for liquid-liquid extraction.

Comment: After boiling coffee and distilled water, I added sodium carbonate. Then filtered through a separatory funnel.

Answer (score -1):

For analysis you need a method to tell the difference between caffeine and other chemicals. Let's say that you dissolve a 1 g mixture of caffeine and contaminant. You can be sure that you have no more than 1 g of caffeine dissolved, but that doesn't tell you much. You can measure concentration of contaminant, convert to weight and subtract it to get the amount of caffeine. This is impractical, because you don't know what the contaminant is.

You can use iodometric titration (http://www.hkasme.org/News/818/Report_6B_Christiam%2520Alliance%2520SC%2520Chan%2520Memorial%2520Secondary%2520School_Chemical_test_for_caffeine.pdf), but this gives you the sum of all oxidizable compounds including caffeine.

You need to tell more about the instruments you have, so that we can help to choose you the right ones.